# Rally Java Rest Unknownhost Exception

Tags: java, rest, rally

I copied the code example that "illustrates how to query for the top 5 highest priority defects" found at the bottom of the [Java Toolkit for Rally Rest](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api) page.

I changed the username and password accordingly, but I am getting an `UnknownHostException`.

Here is the stacktrace:

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: rally1.rallydev.com
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:849)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1202)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1153)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1083)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1019)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doRequest(RallyRestApi.java:253)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doGet(RallyRestApi.java:323)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.query(RallyRestApi.java:179)
    at com.jdes.AgileToRally.AgileToRally.main(AgileToRally.java:37)`

Line 37: `QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(defects);`

I've tried changing the server name, username, and password, but I have had no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a proxy server in the way.

```
restApi.setProxy(new URI(proxyserver));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your stack trace it would appear your machine is attempting to look up the IPV6 address for `rally1.rallydev.com` and it's failing because it doesn't have one (and then not falling back to IPV4). This indicates a problem with your machine's config (or the DNS server it's using) more than a problem in Java.

That being said, you can force the JVM to prefer IPV4 which should solve your problem:

```
prompt> java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ...
```

If you're using an IDE you need to configure it to pass `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to java when you run your program.

Comment: add something like this: `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");`  ?

Comment: @MikeB - To be honest you'd have to try it. Without researching it I'm uncertain as to when that particular system property is read by the JVM/Networking classes and so changing it after application startup may not have any effect.

Comment: I tried passing that variable in many ways, and none of them got me a different result. Do you think the problem might be in `log4j` stuff?

Comment: @MikeB - the *actual* problem is that your machine is trying to use IPV6. Looking at that stack trace again it's possible that apache's `SystemDefaultDnsResolver` class doesn't respect that system property. I don't have a machine configured to use IPV6 at all so I'm afraid I can't reproduce your failure. And no, log4j has nothing to do with networking or DNS.